# Testing, Issue Tracking, Continuous Integration -- recommended standard tooling for GAE and Android apps

Tags: google-app-engine, continuous-integration, google-cloud-endpoints, android-testing, gradle-android-test-plugi

I wanted to solicit some opinions on what would be ideal tools for the job. I'd like to ideally use as few as possible and as tightly integrated as possible. (I've read about 20 different threads on this and have some experience at work as well)

For any of those, I would favor integrated solutions (so for example if a feature as a native capability of Android Studio, I'd rather use it)

1) testing

- GAE backend -- LocalServiceTestHelper testing, regular unit testing
- App frontend -- Roboelectric, Robotium, Monkey

2) test coverage -- EMMA??? I think TeamCity comes with that as well. anything else?

3) VCS -- Git/Github

4) issue detection + tracking

- GAE backend -- dev console, logging
- App frontent-- Crashlytics, debug builds local-log as well

Should I go with the integrated issue tracking in Github, or try JIRA? Crashlytics seems to have integration with both which is good, or is there a different preferred tool by the community?

5) CI

- GAE backend -- Jenkins? TeamCity? Perhaps some google solution in dev?
- App frontend -- Jenkins? TeamCity?

6) Communicating with your users -- an integrated solution that can update facebook, twitter, google+ and potentially a forum-based community site. Any nifty solutions in that space?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I would like to introduce my library for tracking issues exactly from your application. You can read more about by this link http://busylee999.github.io/issue-handler/

Comment: Please visit www.heroku.com. It is one of my favorite PAAS. It comes with all tools you need. Plugins can be configured for CI and continuous deployment. As it provides all the infrastructure for an end to end development DevOps style, you can also use it to use other PAAS like AWS or google's

Comment: Have you looked at Jira?

Comment: While this question does bring up excellent discussion points, it is not one that can have a specific technical answer.  The appropriateness of tools for continuous integration using Google App Engine depends on business needs, scale, budget, development team, skills, etc.  I strongly suggest posting this interesting question/discussion on the [App Engine Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine) for a hopefully lively and heated exchange!

Comment: add this as the answer and i will accept it, even though it's technically not an answer :) and i'll close the question with a link to the google group discussion

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/cHQpaM-LbEc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this question does bring up excellent discussion points, it is not one that can have a specific technical answer.  The appropriateness of tools for continuous integration using Google App Engine depends on business needs, scale, budget, development team, skills, etc.

I strongly suggest posting this interesting question/discussion on the [App Engine Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine) for a hopefully lively and heated exchange.  Should you choose to do so, please post a link to the thread here in a comment so others finding this post can follow through.

Comment: done: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/cHQpaM-LbEc